# Clear SuggestBox on blur in GWT

Tags: gwt, suggestbox

I have a SuggestionBox in GWT. Is there a way to clear it when it blurs (unless the user made a selection, in which case an action should happen)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one using `ValueChangeHandler`:

**Note**: `ValueChange` event has same behavior as `Blue` event but it is fired only if value is changed in `SuggestBox`.

```
class MyMultiWordSuggestOracle extends MultiWordSuggestOracle {
    private Set<String> values = new HashSet<String>();

    @Override
    public void add(String value) {
        super.add(value);
        values.add(value);
    }

    @Override
    public void clear(){
        super.clear();
        values.clear();
    }

    public boolean contains(String value) {
        return values.contains(value);
    }
}
```

You code:

```
    final MyMultiWordSuggestOracle oracle = new MyMultiWordSuggestOracle();
    oracle.add("A");
    oracle.add("AB");        
    oracle.add("BCD");
    oracle.add("BCDE");        

    final SuggestBox suggestionBox = new SuggestBox(oracle);
    suggestionBox.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<String> event) {
            if (!oracle.contains(event.getValue())) {
                suggestionBox.setValue("");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this causes the SuggestBox to miss when an item in the dropdown is clicked.

Comment: May be due to case sensitive values here `if(!oracle.equals(event.getValue()))`. Print the value of `event.getValue()`.

Comment: I don't think so. Its working perfectly. Please can you share some piece of your code?

Comment: According to the documentation, oracle is a SuggestionOracle while event.getValue() can only return a String.

Comment: Are you using `com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.MultiWordSuggestOracle`?

Comment: Yes, I am using `com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.MultiWordSuggestOracle` .

Comment: Currently, I am adding both a ValueChangeHandler and a SelectionHandler to the SuggestBox. The ValueChangeHandler fires first and clears the field, so the SelectionHandler never fires.

Comment: That will not help: When I click on a suggestion, `event.getValue()` is still the text that was entered (eg, if valid options are "AB", "AC", and "BC" and the user has entered "A" and is hovering over "AC", then `event.getValue()` will return "A")

Comment: I have updated my post. Please have a look. It will work in case sensitive values.

Comment: What does it mean of hovering? you haven't clicked on it. on Tab focused suggestion is selected.

Comment: This worked with two exceptions: If the user has entered a valid value but clicked off the field, it does not clear; and if the user clicks inside of a `com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Frame`, the text clears but the suggestion list remains exactly as it was.

Answer (score 0):

Add a BlurHandler:

```
suggestionBox.getValueBox().addBlurHandler(new BlurHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onBlur(BlurEvent event) {
        // your code goes here
    }
});
```

Comment: Your link says otherwise. You confused it with getTextBox().